# InflateExcpetion: Error inflating class Seekbar (sorry, not yet implemented) Robolectric

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, junit, robolectric

I am trying to test a fragment in an activity which has a custom drawable for the seekbar track. The test is crashing with the above error. Can anyone please suggest anything that can help get the test to run?
Thanks in advance.

Stack trace:

```
android.view.InflateException: XML file build/intermediates/res/merged/fakeAnalytics/debug/layout/fragment_connected_to_headphone.xml line #-1 (sorry, not yet implemented): Error inflating class SeekBar

Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: File build/intermediates/res/drawable/abc_seekbar_track_material.xml from drawable resource ID #0x7f020038
```

Comment: Do you have any other working Robolectric tests?

Comment: Yes. As a matter of fact, if I comment on the seekbar usages, all the tests for the current activity also work.